Why (4 V 1.5 Ah) sealed lead acid battery charger using LM317T doesn't work?
Link to Falstad simulation.
The circuit below shows the 4 V, 1.5 Ah sealed lead acid battery charger. LM317T with heatsink is used which has 9V DC as input. The Zener diode breakdown voltage is 4.7 V. There is also a normal PN-diode (1N4007) that has 0.4 V forward cutin voltage. The Ref voltage at 180 Ω is 1.23 V. The problem which I have faced is.
I have built two same independent circuits from the circuit diagram which is shown below. I have changed potentiometer and the maximum output voltage for one circuit is 4.0 V and for another circuit it is 4.5 V. I have cross checked my two independent circuits many times for any wrong connections, even I have provided 12 V input to LM317T (through 12 V AC transformer and bridge rectifier), but the output of the two circuits stays at 4.0 V and 4.5 V only.
With 9 V input, the LM317T output is 7.3 V (when connection to PN-diode is removed). But as soon as connection to PN-diode is made, the output voltages of two independent circuits falls to 4V and 4.5V.
When input is 9 V, below are the voltages and currents which are observed. The >ener diode 4.7 V (never enters into breakdown in both the circuits, which I have built on breadboard).
VBE = 0.67 V
VCB = 3 V
ib = 21.3 μA
ic = 6.75 mA
My intention is to connect 4 V 1.5 Ah sealed lead battery at the output of the circuit. When battery gets charged to 5.2 V. The BJT switches off the LM317T so that overcharging can be prevented. I know that I can do the same with op-amp. But I like to know why my circuit differs from simulation. I have done same simulation in Proteus software and Falstad website, both simulations have same results.


I would add a resistor from the bottom end of the Zener diode to the negative rail.  Leakage current through the zener diode will turn the transistor on way before it is supposed to be on.  Try about 100 Ohms.

sir (Dwayne Reid)....i made the changes which u have told..now my practical circuit has made zener to work.i will test the circuit for automatic cutoff by connecting a 4v-1.5AH battery.After the test,i will post the final design so that it will be useful for everyone.

This design seems to bypass the LM317's voltage regulation. A low resistance path through Zener diode to ground may prevent the 1N4007 from doing it's full good (prevent drawing current from output when input is 0 V). I find SE questions to work best when there is an explicit question, if it wasn't for some bold face text, I'd never have guessed what your's may be.

@greybeard,i am new to the stack exchange and this is my first question which i have posted in this website and so pardon me for any mistakes which i have made in describing my problem.As told by Dwayne Reid.i have added a resistance 200 ohms to the bottom end of Zener diode and i also changed Zener to 4.3v (Vz) so that LM317T will cutoff when battery connected at the output reaches 5.1v.sir(grey beard) i cant understand the side effects of adding resistor which affects 1N4007 operation.can u please elaborate.i have made changes to simulation , link is https://tinyurl.com/23m2ew3o

@greybeard,sir from the comment which u have posted, what i understood is,the battery will get drained,if the LM317T output voltage gets turned down by BC547 transistor.so please can u suggest a solution to the problem.my problem is
Zener doesnt turn on without resistor at the bottom end of Zener.but if i put resistor,the battery when it reaches 5.1v(if 4.3v Zener is used ) will cut off the LM317T and the battery will get discharged by low resistance path created by Zener and resistor.

will get drained is overstating the issue. @4.4 V, 25°C the reverse current through the diode should be in the 1 nA ballpark - be sure to clean flux & finger prints to not increase that. I can't seem to get falstead to simulate a 4.4 V source at the output even with input set to 0 V. I'd expepct Zener current to be in the single digit nicroampere ballpark as shown (and near "room temperature").

My circuit design doesn't work.
I have built the circuit to check how much time battery will take for full charge. The current to the 4 V, 1.5 Ah is 88 mA, so to fully charge the battery I need 12 to 15 hours.  I am discarding above circuit and going to start a new one, so I am closing this question.  Thanks for all the suggestions I received from the community.
From a google search, I understood that a 4 V, 1.5 Ah battery can be charged at C/4 current (maximum current allowed).
https://www.instructables.com/Simple-4V-Lead-Acid-Battery-Charger/
I will try to implement the design shown in above link and I will submit  the results in new post.
